# Changing from Z to A in an Encrypt Program

Tags: java, encryption, ascii

I am writing an encrypt program in Java in which I need to change the input string by a certain value. I am having a problem when I get to the Z and need to change it into an A not the next character in the ASCII code. How would I change it from Z to A? I know that I would also need to change the value that it is being encrypted by but I am drawing a blank on how to change Z to A in ASCII.

Comment: That's known as a Caesar or shift cipher. Just don't use it for any public real / live data - it's not secure at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to shift all letters by `n`:

```
((letter - 'A' + n) % 26) + 'A'
```

And to decode:

```
((letter - 'A' + 26 - n) % 26) + 'A'
```

Comment: And if I want to shift by a user input value, the 1 would just change to whatever they input?

Comment: Yes.  Modulo 26, of course, and check if it's a capital or lowercase letter first ;)

Comment: Now, what if I was doing the decrypt for the same function. How would I unshift all of the letters?

Comment: Just use -n instead of +n to get the original letter back.

Comment: What do you mean by n? Do you mean the shift value? I tried that and the letters did not wrap around. For example: once it got to a, it then went to ' instead of z. How would I change the wrap-around for the decrypt?

Comment: Yeah, I meant the shift value, and sorry, I forgot about how Java acts when taking the modulus of a negative number.  I will update my post to explain how to decode.

Answer (score 2):

No sure why you are using ASCII. Just use char

```
char ch = ...
if (ch >= 'A' && ch < 'Z') ch++;
else if (ch == 'Z') ch = 'A';
else if (ch >= 'a' && ch < 'z') ch++;
else if (ch == 'z') ch = 'z';
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [sverre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679376/changing-from-z-to-a-in-an-encrypt-program/5679407#5679407):

```
    String s = "AGJAJAJMLVJHNJAFVZVZJADFYAQ";
    StringBuffer e = new StringBuffer();
    char[] cs = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
        e.append((char)('A' + (cs[i] - 'A' + 1) % 26));
    }
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(e.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if that does the trick:

```
public String encode(String str) {
      String res = new String();
      for (char c : str) {
           if (Character.isUpperCase(c))
               (c == 'Z') ? res.append('A') : res.append(c+1);
           else throw new Exception(c + " is not a A-Z character");
      }
      return res;
}
```